# How to set the overflow property of errorTextStyle from TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, flutter-textformfield

I'm trying to do set the overflow of the errorText in TextFormField widget. As you can see in the following picture, the remaining error text goes into the ellipsis.

[image]

I want my error message to completely visible. I've tried to set the overflow from the errorTextStyle, but it doesn't work.

```dart
errorStyle: TextStyle(
                color: AppColors.secondaryRed,
                overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
              ),
```

Am I missing something? Or is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: use-    errorMaxLines: 2

Answer (score 1):

Inside InputDecoration put this line of code errorMaxLines: 2:

```
InputDecoration(
  errorMaxLines: 2,
  errorStyle: TextStyle(
      color: AppColors.secondaryRed,
      overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
   ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `errorMaxLines: 2` under the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not handled by error style, You can add another text which represent your error, i.e. in your validator function you have to update errorString.

Code here:

```
//Variable
String errorString = "";

//widget
   Column(
     children: [
        Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: TextFormField(
         controller: emailController,
           validator: (value) {
               if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  errorString = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled";
                } else {
                   errorString = "";
                }
                return null;
            },
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        Align(
           alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
             child: Text(errorString))
     ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add  `errorMaxLines: 3` in the `InputDecoration`

**Output**:

[image]

**Complete Code:**

```
TextFormField(
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          errorMaxLines: 3,    // Add this
          errorStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
            overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
          ),
        ),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value?.isEmpty == true) {
            return 'Please enter a value Please enter a value Please enter a value Please enter a value';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
```